# Magento graphQL Extending ProductInterface error : Expected a value of type \"Int\" but received

Tags: magento2, graphql, pwa

I have created a custom module that will override the ProductInterface class in graphQl
[image]

[image]

as you can se i have mentioned the image_banner as string
and i checked the banner.php its also returing string
but in graqphl response im getting this
[image]

please help

Comment: Did you got any solution for this? I am facing same issue while extending category interface and adding custom category attribute

Comment: I am able to resolve the similar issue. Can you please update your question with code for attribute creation "image_banner"

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have modified the graphql schema after your first query.
The change that you have made will probably be change Int to String in the schema.

Perhaps you can solve it by running setup:upgrade.

I would recommend to use https://github.com/mage2tv/magento-cache-clean which will automatically flush the stitched schema when you make modifications to a schema file.

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide errors from var/log/exception.log file? It looks like error in     logic and not in graphql-schema.